# Twitter gem get location of tweet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I've been messing around with the twitter rails API and I'm having trouble getting a tweet's location.  This always seems to fail and not return anything.  I've also tried doing tweet.coordinates but it doesn't seem to work.

```
tweets = client.user_timeline("gems")
puts "size : #{tweets.size}"  
tweets.each do |tweet|
    if(tweet.place)
       puts tweet.place.attributes
    end
end
```

I'm using the following twitter gem.
https://github.com/sferik/twitter

EDIT:

```
tweets = client.search("a", geocode: "40.7128,-74.0059,50mi").take(100)
tweets.each do |tweet|
    if tweet.place?
        puts tweet.place.full_name
     elsif tweet.geo?
        puts "geofound"
    elsif tweet.user.location?
        puts tweet.user.location
     end
```

So I tried the above code looking for tweets that have geocodes, but it seems that none of them have a place or geo field and it always returns the tweet.user.location, but that's not very accurate.  The output just has a lot of New York's, but also a bunch from other cities as well so I don't really know how Twitter got those queries when the other cities don't exist/are far away from NY.  Am I missing another location field?  I also noted that the number of outputs doesn't equal the size of the tweet array.

https://pastebin.com/eW18Ri2S

Here's an example output

Comment: What is your output? Does it show the size correctly? You can try `puts tweet.inspect` on the first line of the loop body to see if the tweet is present.

Comment: the size is 20.  I've tried outputting the text and they're all fine.

Comment: Do the tweets actually include geo metadata? Not all tweets do - need to choose the right account. Even in Twitter's example output, place is null https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: @KZeng can you do `tweet.inspect` and paste the result along with the question?

Comment: Yea I noticed that not all of them had the correct metadata so I tried searching for things with a geocode option but still no luck.  Are tweets with the geo metadata rare?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the `twitter` gem documentation, you should user `place?` or `geo?` methods.

> Null Objects
>
> In version 4, methods you would expect to return a Twitter object
>   would return nil if that object was missing. This may have resulted in
>   a `NoMethodError`. To prevent such errors, you may have introduced
>   checks for the truthiness of the response, for example:

```
status = client.status(55709764298092545)
if status.place   
  # Do something with the Twitter::Place object
elsif status.geo   
  # Do something with the Twitter::Geo object
end
```

> In version 5, all such
>   methods will return a `Twitter::NullObject` instead of `nil`. This should
>   prevent NoMethodError but may result in unexpected behavior if you
>   have truthiness checks in place, since everything is truthy in Ruby
>   except false and nil. For these cases, there are now predicate
>   methods:

```
 status = client.status(55709764298092545)
 if status.place?
   # Do something with the Twitter::Place object
 elsif status.geo?
   # Do something with the Twitter::Geo object
 end
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I'm still having some issues.  I did the inspect and they all seem to have some twitter ID's.